# Error while viewing saved procedure - sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure in sql as below:

```
Create procedure spAddEmployee  
@Name nchar(10),  
@Gender nchar(10),  
@City nchar(10),  
@DateOfBirth DateTime  
as  
Begin  
 Insert into tblEmployee (Name, Gender, City, DateOfBirth)  
 Values (@Name, @Gender, @City, @DateOfBirth)  
End
```

It was created successfully. But when I try to execute using the query

exec spAddEmployee;

its showing error as below:

Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure spAddEmployee, Line 0
Procedure or function 'spAddEmployee' expects parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.

Its showing @Name parameter is not supplied. But I have already done it. Please help me figure out whats the issue.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to view it"? Your screenshot doesn't make much sense to me. This is the kind of error you will get when executing the stored procedure, not when creating it... Please [edit] your question to include the code that generated the error (No screenshot, please, just formatted text)

Comment: Show the query that you use to execute your procedure

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences. I have edited the question. Please check and advise

Comment: "But I have already done it" - unless this is a language issue, this is not clear. When you execute `spAddEmployee`, you're expected to provide a *value* for the `@Name` parameter. But your `exec` line appears to include *no* values after the name of the stored procedure to execute.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute an SP, you must provide all values for parameters which don't have default values.

[Specify Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/specify-parameters)